# Why e.status is getting as undefined in success function of ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting my reponse as {"status":true}. But when I do console.log(e.status) I am getting as undefined.

When I do console.log(e) I get {"status":true}

This is my ajax request

```
$("#msgfrm").on("submit", function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxinsert.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      name: name,
      email: email
    },
    success: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log(e.status);
      if (e.status === 'true') {
        alert("success");
      } else {
        alert("Fail");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Please tell me what is my error??

Comment: What happens when you run `console.log(typeof e);`? I'm GUESSING that will print `string` and not `object`.

Comment: ^ Adding to that point, you probably just need to `JSON.parse(e)` to turn it from a JSON `string` into an actual `object`. That said, you might want to verify in such a case that you're returning `"true"` (as a `string`) and not `true` (as a `boolean`), as your `if` condition is expecting a `string`.

Comment: yes it is printing string

Comment: but i have passed  $response = array(
        'status' => true,
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
}

Comment: Set `dataType:'json'` since it seems you haven't set content type header at server. `e` will then be parsed object

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are getting result as string. Try parsing it before using it.

```
    success:function(e){
                   var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(e);
                    alert(obj);
                    alert(obj.status);
}
```

Comment: better to just set dataType and parsing will be done internally or go to error if there is a parsing error